# Having Issue On Generating Random Numbers More Than Random Rage Number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to generate `30` Random Numbers between 1 to 20. I am using this code but this is making conflict since the loop number is bigger than the Random range (I guess!)

```
  var arr1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 30;) {
      var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
      if ( arr1.indexOf(ran) == -1)
         arr1[i++] = ran;
    }
```

can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can prevent this to create 30 random numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the third argument on your for statement.
Try this:

```
var arr1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    arr1[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a fiddle here , have a look

https://jsbin.com/kagixi/edit?html,js,output

In first case, we are updating values by iterating over all the indices.

```
var list = new Array(30).fill(0);

list.forEach(function(d, index){
  list[index] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
});
console.log(list);
```

Another way of doing this is to initialize array just to loop and then simply create a new array with same length or replace the existing one as I did in this example.

```
var list2 = new Array(30).fill(0);

list2 = list2.map(function(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates an infinite loop.

Your random numbers are between 1 and 20 but you want 30 of them in your array. The check for duplicates in the line `if ( arr1.indexOf(ran) == -1)` is guaranteed to return false after 20 iterations, creating an infinite loop.

Comment: No, his code does not create infinite loop, he is incrementing index `arr1[i++] = ran;` which will break the loop as desired..

Comment: Have you tried running the code? I ran it and encountered an infinite loop.

Comment: The thing is, he wants 30 elements but only 20 possible numbers. It is impossible to have an array of 30 unique elements with 20 candidates.

Comment: Well, that's what his original code looked like it was doing